# mouseout closes the trigger and not the target

Tags: javascript

I have set a popup to open at mouse over on an element. The popup should close when the cursor is off it.
For some reason the popup window closes when the cursor is right off its opener button, instead.
You can see an example here:
http://www.friends.wwz.co.il/Lab/Gefen/Generali/es/popup.html

Please try to hover with the mouse on the "lee mas" button. A popup will open. It should close at hovering off it. But instead it closes at hovering off the lee mas button, so it closes immediately.
Any idea where do I go wrong?
Many thanks in advance for you advice

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are attaching hover events to the button. Once you hover out of the button element, it fires the hoverOut button.

So the ideal course of action can be:

- Bind hover event to the button.
- Once hovered, a pop-up is dynamically added.
- Then, a hover event is bounded to the pop.
- And the code of dissolving the pop-up is attached in the hover-out function.

So that when actually the cursor is hovered out of the pop-up it dissolves.

Apart from that, Just have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/4RgTS/). It has two hyperlinks for hover. The first is the one you are facing. The second one is the one you are looking for. :D

Code for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggleSwitch_j").hover(

    function() {
      $("#theBox_3").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
      $("#theBox_3").slideUp(500);
    });


  $("#StayOpen").hover(
    function() {
      $("#theBox_2").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
      $("#theBox_2").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eef;
}
#theBox_3,
#theBox_2 {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddf;
}
#toggleSwitch_j,
#StayOpen {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This layout will only keep the hidden div visible as long as you point to the link
<br>You'll never be able to reach anything inside the div
<br><a href="#" id="toggleSwitch_j">jQuery Hover</a>
<div id="theBox_3">Peek-a-boo!</div>

<hr>This layout puts the link and hidden div inside a wrapper - hovering anywhere inside the wrapper expands the hidden div, so you can reach content inside it. This would be handy if you need to put links or form elements inside the hidden div, instead of
just text to read.
<div id="StayOpen">
  <a href="#" id="toggleSwitch_2">jQuery Hover</a>
  <div id="theBox_2">Peek-a-boo!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my answer, and thank you for your answer - in fact I lost hope on Stack Overflow, and didn't expect to get an answer, so I didn't eve bother to check, and that's a shame. 
In the meantime I already found another solution that worked - but reading your comment, I just realize now what was my main mistake. I didn't consider the hover event being twofold, and wasn't aware of the fact that it also handles the mouse out and away from the button itself. So your answer helped me clear this issue. Thanks!